# Why won't Dev-C++ allow me to use std::list?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I have a tiny snippet of code that seems absolutely fine:

```cpp
#include <iostream> //Access standard IO library
#include <string>   //Access type 'string'
#include <list>     //Access type 'list'

using namespace std; //Use standard library namespace

int main ()
{
    list<string> strungos {"No", "Yes"};
    cout << strungos.back();
    return 0;
}
```

but every time I try to compile I get the error: `expected primary-expression before "strungos", expected ';' before "strungos"`. I don't know why this is happening; the same code runs perfectly fine when I paste it into an [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler). After testing this again with different types, it seems like I can't use `std::list` at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add compiler flag `-std=c++11` (or later version)

Comment: @M.M. where does the compiler flag go? I only started c++ yesterday, so I'm not entirely used to it.

Comment: IDK, I don't use dev-c++  (it's quite old). try googling how to enable c++11 in dev-c++ or check its documentation

Comment: @KennyOstrom Dev-C++ (in the title)

Comment: Depending on how old the compiler is, it may not be able to handle initializer lists at all. You could just push_back on the next two lines to build the list you want.